# Kafka StickyAssignor breaking delivery to single consumer in the group

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a topic with a single partition and two consumer processes that form a consumer group.

This way a message is always delivered to a single consumer. The StickyAssignor is used to prefer consumers that are already assigned to partition on rebalance.

I've been playing with this setup a bit and discovered that under certain circumstances, the messages are delivered to both consumers, which breaks the purpose of consumer group.

The scenario is following:

1. Start consumer C1
2. C1 begins receiving messages
3. Start consumer C2
4. C2 doesn't receive any messages - thanks to StickyAssignor strategy that prefers C1
5. Freeze C1 process - (using Java debugger - stopping all threads)
6. C2 takes over - begins receiving messages
7. Unfreeze C1 process
8. Now **both C1 and C2 receive messages** despite being in the same group

When using RangeAssignor/RoundRobinAssignor, this does not happen.

Am I missing something or is this a bug in Kafka?

Here's my consumer code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
props.put("group.id", "test");
props.put("client.id", consumerId);
props.put("enable.auto.commit", "false");
props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
props.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
props.put("partition.assignment.strategy", StickyAssignor.class.getName());
KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props);

consumer.subscribe(Collections.singleton("my-events"));



while (true) {
    ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
    for (ConsumerRecord<String, String> record : records)
        System.out.printf("offset = %d, key = %s, value = %s%n", record.offset(), record.key(), record.value());
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that C1 and C2 both receive messages on a long term basis (i.e. not just resends since the last partition offset commit?) When do you commit offsets?

Comment: Exactly. Been watching the output for couple of minutes and both instances kept receiving. I use the default auto offset commit.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this bug in the sticky assignor code. A [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7026) has been created to track the issue.